# get only abstract (parent) vars for php class?

Tags: php, inheritance, properties

I want to create a function to populate properties of an object, some properties will be shared between multiple inherited classes, but some will be specific to the inherited class. I would like to handle the shared properties from the parent and the variant-specific from the inherited classes. (i.e. do the specific stuff in the child then call parent::populateStuff() for the shared things)

Rather than go back over re-hashing all of the variable names, I was looking to use get_class_vars or get_object_vars to get the names of the properties to populate. But when you run get_object_vars($this) you get 'all' of the inherited variables (both parent and inherited) regardless at which level it is called. If I call the specific class name with get_class_vars, I can get the parent-only stuff but I would have no way of seeing what is added or overridden in the inherited class. I would also prefer not to put static class names in the code as it makes it less portable when refactoring.

I did find that I can run get_parent_class($this) in the parent and that works but seems a round-about way to get the local class name. (get_class(self) puked) But at least this works at the parent level.

So my questions are, is there a better way to get the abstract-layer class vars or class name?
And is there a better way to get the inherited only properties? (I can do an array splice with the parent vars, but that would exclude anything overridden)

Comment: I should add, the properties are being populated from two [or more] db tables/queries in each variation. One is specific to the abstract properties, the other specific to the inherited class properties. So it's [almost] one-to-one as far as the values. I could go from the db rows back, but some tables have ids that are used for cross-referencing/linking that I don't need in the classes, and some variants do override values in the first table.

Comment: duh - ok, first question was a brain fart - \_\_CLASS\_\_ gets me what I want on that. ReflectionClass gives me info on what is set where at any given level and I'll use that for now, but I'd still be curious if there is another way without using ReflectionClass

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection, I came up with this and it works, but I'm still wondering if there is a way to do this without invoking reflection class:

```
/**
 * @param object|Zend_Db_Table_Row $row
 */
public function populateThisLayer($row) {
    $reflect = new \ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
    foreach($reflect->getProperties() as $_p) {
        $_k = $_p->name;
        if(($_p->class == __CLASS__) && property_exists($row, $_k)) {
            $this->$_k = (is_numeric($row->$_k)) ? floatval($row->$_k) : $row->$_k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This leads me to yet another question. Is there any way to tell where this function is being called from? If I use it as is, when called from an inherited class, it only populates the parent class properties. I can pass the class in, but it would be nicer if it could figure out if it was called from somewhere within the abstract or from some inheritance layer.